# Determining statement type in PDO

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

Long story short. I have a class which handles database queries and it forks at some point depending from statement type which was passed to it. If it was a `SELECT`, it does something. If it was a (successful) `INSERT`, `UPDATE` or `DELETE` it does something else. I was relying on `PDOStatement::rowCount` to determine it and it worked fine on my previous system. However after porting the class to another server `PDOStatement::rowCount` behavior changed (it now returns the amount of rows returned by the `SELECT` statement). I read in PHP manual that such behavior **may** happen and that it is not consistent and depends from the database.

So my question. Is there another foolproof way to determine what type of statement was passed to the PDO? I guess I could just write a method to analyze the syntax of statement and add it to the class but perhaps there is some other way (built-in method?) in which case I should not try to reinvent the wheel. Thanks.

Comment: look for the keyword in the query passed for preparing a statement?

Comment: Yes, that is an obvious answer. But I was just asking to make sure if I will not be inserting a screw using pliers if there is a screwdriver available next to me.

Answer (score 0):

Set `PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE` attribute at first.

```
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

Then...

```
try {

    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute($values);

    try {

        $rows = $stmt->fetchAll();

        /* The SQL was SELECT */

        $count = count($rows);


    } catch (PDOException $e) {

        /* The SQL was INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE */

        $count = $stmt->rowCount();

    }

} catch (PDOException $e) {

    /* Execution Failure */

    $error = $e->getMessage(); 

}
```